# Use automapper to map entire object to an enum

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

Is it possible to use automapper to determine an enum for the entire object?
Now I get this error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

When I try like

```
var orderType = _mapper.Map<OrderType>(orderData);
```

What I've been trying is:

```
public class Mapper : Profile
{
    public Mapper()
    {
        CreateMap<OrderData, OrderType>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => OrderType.Type1);
    }
    public enum OrderType { Type1, Type2, Type3 }
}
```

Of course there will be some more logic later to determine the correct enum :-)

Comment: You could write custom conversation rules. So yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mistake at startup so it never added the profile to automapper